# Invoke Delphi FMX StringGrid TPopupColumn using the keyboard?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, stringgrid

I have a Delphi 11 FMX project with a StringGrid. I added a TPopupColumn to the StringGrid and added two items in list. The only way I have found to invoke the TPopupColumn and get to those values is by using the mouse.

Is there a way to invoke the TPopupColumn values by using the keyboard?

Comment: Have you tried spacebar?

Comment: Test reveals: when in `TPopupColumn` you can select row with [Tab] (going down) or [Shift][Tab], alternatively [up] [down] arrows. To open the popup menu hit [spacebar]. To select item, use [up] [down] arrows.

Comment: @TomBrunberg thank you. I'll test after lunch.

Comment: @TomBrunberg that is perfect. Had no idea spacebar was the trick. Thank you very much. Please make you comment the answer and I'll vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the spacebar invokes the TPopupColumn.